# Congruential Generators.

Tags: probability, number-theory, statistics, simulation

Find all of the cycles of the following congruential generators. For each
cycle identify which seeds $X_0$ lead to that cycle.
$$(a). X_{n+1} = 9X_n + 3\mod 11$$
$$(b). X_{n+1} = 8X_n + 3\mod 11$$
$$(c). X_{n+1} = 8X_n + 2\mod 12$$

How can i choose the seed,$X_0$, at random ?

#### When will i stop to generate numbers ?

I supposed to draw $X_0$ at random from $0$ to $10$ [since $m=11$]and wrote `R` codes :

```
  X<- 0
  X[1]<-8 # seed ,Xo

 for(i in 2:11){
    X[i]<-(9*X[i-1]+3)%%11
    cat("",9*X[i-1]+3,"",X[i],"\n") 
}

X
```

How can i solve the problem ?

Comment: Since you are asked to find *all* the cycles, you *don't want* to choose the seed at random; rather, you want to choose *every* possible seed, one at a time, systematically. Since you are asked to find the *cycles*, you stop as soon as you generate a number you have already seen generated by whichever seed it is that you are working on. You may be able to save some work by seeing and proving some pattern after the first few calculations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson for (a) do i have to take seed from $0 $ to $10$?

Comment: In principle, yes, although as I say you might notice something along the way that saves you some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $x(n)$ instead of $X_n$.

From $x(n+1) = 9x(n) + 3 \mod 11$, we see $x(n+1) -1 = 9x(n) +2 = 9(x(n) -1) \mod 11$. It is from $2 = -9 \mod 11$. So $(x(n) -1) = 9^n (x(0) -1 ) \mod 11$, $x(n) = 9^n(x(0)-1) +1 \mod 11$.

$9^n$ are $1, 9, 4, 3, 5, 1, \cdots \mod 11$ where $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\cdots$, so in general length of cycle is 5. But if $x_0 = 1$, then $x(n) = 1 \mod 11$ for all $n\ge1$. Since 5 is prime, there could not be any other smaller cycle.

I don't know statistics or probability, but this problem seems to be solved like this way (number theorical way).

On (c), If the problem was not in modulo arithmetic but in real number system, 
$x(n+1) + \frac{2}{7} = 8(x(n)  + \frac{2}{7})$. So, we need $7^{-1} \mod 12$.

Since 12 is not a prime, in general inverse could not exist; but $7\times 7 = 1 \mod 12$, number $7$ has its inverse in $\mod 12$, (c) also could be solved.